# Place group of text and image on same exported PDF page

Tags: page-breaking, minipage

I am new to Tex and this question maybe is not written well, so I will try to explain it better.

I am writing a reference manual where there are a lot of "blocks" that all have the same structure: a piece of text (maybe one or two short paragraphs) and then an image (tipically a screenshot).

I would like to be able to define such a block in a way that, when exporting document to PDF, the output is on the same page. I understand that there will be some pages half-filled when this "block" begins and does not fit into the current page. In these cases, I expect the block to be placed entirely at the next page.

I have been playing with `\begin{samepage}`, `\begin{minipage}` and things like that (searching a lot in this same web) with no luck. Obviously I am doing something wrong, or taking a bad approach to solve the problem.

Take a look at my code:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Phasellus leo ipsum, dictum non auctor quis, euismod vitae enim. Mauris varius.

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{center} \includegraphics[scale={0.7}]{IMG1} \end{center}
  \caption{Image caption}
  \label{fig:IMG1}
\end{figure}
```

I would like all this piece of text (2 paragraphs) and one figure to be always in the same page.

Can this be achieved? In fact I thought I got it when I discovered `\begin{minipage}`! If this is the case, can you please write down a short code showing how to use it? (remember I am a newbie and some obvious things are not so obvious for me right now).

**Edit:** I will try @Werner tip, but I am already using a \newcommand to short all the previously written \begin{figure} environment. As this:

```
\newcommand{\figureSF}[4]{
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center} \includegraphics[scale={#4}]{#1} \end{center}
    \caption{#2}
\label{#3}
\end{figure}
}
```

So the previous piece of code turns into:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Phasellus leo ipsum, dictum non auctor quis, euismod vitae enim. Mauris varius.

\figureSF{IMG1}{Image caption}{fig:IMG1}{0.7}
```

As this new command accept only 4 parameters, is there an easy way to modify it to handle the situation you are describing?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're writing a bunch of text and then inbetween there are these "blocks" that you want to be "kept together." For this, seeing as you currently already use a `figure` environment for the image, you can include the paragraph text within your `figure`. TeX does not care what's containing inside the environment - it could be a table, an image, some text, whatever. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}
  \hrulefill\par
  \lipsum[3-4]
  \centering\includegraphics[scale={0.7}]{IMG1}
  \caption{Some caption}\label{fig:label1}
  \hrulefill
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5-6]
\lipsum[7-8]
\begin{figure}
  \hrulefill\par
  \lipsum[9-10]
  \centering\includegraphics[scale={0.7}]{IMG2}
  \caption{Some other caption}\label{fig:label2}
  \hrulefill
\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-12]
\end{document}​
```

I've added an `\hrulefill` above and below the floating "block" to make it clear that the text content floats with the image. Also, the `[demo]` option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) is just for this example since I don't have the images you mention/use.

Note that all float-related restrictions (and benefits!) pertain to this usage. For example, the portion of text/float allowed at the top/bottom of a page, etc. More on this is available from the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) (section **6 Float layouts**, p 21).

In terms of the figure placement, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) (and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764)).

Bundling this into a single command is also possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\figureSF}[5]{%
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \hrulefill\par
    #1\par\bigskip
    \centering\includegraphics[scale=#5]{#2}
    \caption{#3}\label{#4}
    \hrulefill
  \end{figure}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\figureSF{\lipsum[3-4]}{IMG1}{Some caption}{fig:label1}{0.7}
\lipsum[5-6]
\lipsum[7-8]
\figureSF{\lipsum[9-10]}{IMG2}{Some other caption}{fig:label2}{0.7}
\lipsum[11-12]
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Thanks! (I still can not upvote you). I have edited my original question (addition at the end). Is your tip still useful in that situation?

Comment: Nice! I have just tried it and it worked well. Now the problem is related to the text next to this "group", which is rendered before it. I need to read your links and better understand float placement

Comment: @ismdiego: Yes, you can still use your approach. I've updated your `\figureSF` command to now take 5 arguments, where the first is the preceding text, followed by the regular content you have.